# Cisco AXL Error Codes - Access to documentation, database table, etc

Tags: cisco-axl

I found some `AXL Error Codes`, 5000 - 5007 (5006 missing), but there have to be more.

For example I also received a -239.

Is there a documentation on the AXL Error Codes?
Perhaps there is a database table containing the AXL Error Codes.

Like the database tables from Cisco Unified Communications Manager 12.5(1) Database Dictionary:

https://developer.cisco.com/docs/axl/#!12-5-cucm-data-dictionary

There are tables like

```
typeadminerror
typedberrors
```

containing error codes and messages, but none for the AXL Error Codes (like mention above, 5000 - 5007, -239).

Where are those AXL Error Codes defined, and the messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AXL error codes are not documented and may change per release (though very unlikely to see anything but additions), but may be useful when working with [Cisco Developer Support](https://developer.cisco.com/site/support/).

Examining the [AXL service logs](https://developer.cisco.com/docs/axl/#!enable-and-gather-axl-api-logs/gather-the-axl-logs-using-the-rtmt-tool) on CUCM may provide some clues for the errors as you encounter them.